# memory allocation of 100 bytes failed

Tags: memory, memory-management, rust

I have some code that needs to create a large array. 
On my local computer (OSX) the program runs ok. 
However when I try to run the program on Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet I get the following error:

```
memory allocation of 100 bytes failedAborted
```

There isn't any other information provided in the output, but I think it has to do with initializing the vector.

```
fn example() {
    let n = 25;
    let mut dp: Vec<Vec<f32>> = vec![vec![-1.0; n]; 2i32.pow(n as u32) as usize];
}
```

The size of that vector can get quite large in some instances. Is there a better way to create this large vector or is this caused by a system limit of memory?

Comment: for what value of `n`, what are the spec of your machine, "is this caused by a system limit of memory" obviously - -

Comment: Suppose `n = 25`, so your inner vectors require 100 bytes each.  The outer vector has length `2**25`, so the total size is `(2**25)*100` which is more than 3 gigabytes.  How much memory do you have in your DO droplet?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that makes sense, I have 3GB and I can run examples of `n=20` but fail for `n=25` I will increase the memory limits on my droplet and see what happens

Comment: Aside from the memory issues, you should use 1 << n, as the outer size. Aside from being more efficient (it is a shift rather than a general power), no casts are needed, as everything works as a usize.

Comment: If you are willing to use the nightly Rust and unsafe code, you could use the [System allocator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.System.html), that will let you have more control about your memory.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Actually, I find `pow` more readable. It could be written better though, since `usize` also has [pow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.pow): `2_usize.pow(n as u32)`. I guess the OP following the compiler suggestion to add `_i32` and then was stuck with a cast.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah you are right, I was following the compiler suggestion, still new to rust and learning about the number types, I'll try out your suggestion!

Comment: @ThomasC: Nothing wrong in following the suggestions, they're specifically here to be followed. I am more disappointed in the poor suggestion here :/

Comment: What's the right way to check how much memory does my machine have for such allocations in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've requested a Vec that's too large and ran out of memory. When this happens, Rust will abort the program.

The failure to allocate 100 bytes, rather than >3GB is surprising, but it's probably because behavior of memory allocation on Linux is very unintuitive. Linux pretends to have an infinite amount of memory available, and will allow overly large allocations (overcommit) until it can't bluff any more.

You can mitigate this somewhat by using [`try_reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.try_reserve):

```rust
let mut vec = Vec::new();
let size = 2.pow(25);

// this may fail, but won't hard abort
vec.try_reserve(size)?; 

// now you can safely add up to the `size` to the vec
vec.resize(size, -1.0);
```

There is [fallible_collections](https://lib.rs/crates/fallible_collections) crate that has more OOM-handling methods for `Vec` and others.

Another thing to consider is setting your own hard limit for memory usage for your Rust program using [the `cap` allocator wrapper](https://lib.rs/crates/cap). This lets you avoid wrath of Linux's OOM killer, and limit your program's allocations before they become a machine-wide problem.

Comment: How can I check (not necessarily programically) how much memory does my machine have for such allocations in Rust?

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov On most systems the `top` command will show you memory stats at the top. However, note that Linux and most OSes with virtual memory can't give you a straight answer to how much "free" memory there is, because they use very complex tricks with memory reuse and lazy allocation. They don't know!